# XSLT 2.0 if condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Need help on XSLT 2.0 transformation.

Input xml :

```
<Employee>
<Post>Manager</Post>
</Employee>
```

pseudo code :

```
if(Employee/Post = 'Manager') then
Associate/High = 'Band'
else
Associate/Low = 'Band'
```

Output xml :

```
<Associate>
<High>Band</High>
</Associate>

<Associate>
<Low>Band</Low>
</Associate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct an element dynamically with `xsl:element`. Other than that, your pseudo code is already pretty accurate.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
      <Associate>
          <xsl:element name="{if (Post = 'Manager') then 'High' else 'Low'}">
              <xsl:value-of select="'Band'"/>
          </xsl:element>
      </Associate>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Associate>
   <High>Band</High>
</Associate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a template

```
<xsl:template match="Employee">
  <Associate>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Associate>
</xsl:template>
```

and then

```
<xsl:template match="Employee/Post[. = 'Manager']">
  <High>Band</High>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee/Post[not(. = 'Manager')]">
  <Low>Band</Low>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If High and Low are in different levels like `<Associate> <Header>
<High>Band</High></Header>
</Associate>`  and `<Associate> <Detail>
<Low>Band</Low></Detail>
</Associate>`  , then how will be the xslt?

Comment: If it's just the output which is different, then just output directly the nodes you need in the templates. Like <xsl:template match=...><Detail><Low>...</Low></Detail></xsl:template>

Comment: @user3480752, please add the changed requirements to your question, it is not clear whether both your input and desired output have various levels of nesting or solely the new output. If it is solely the output and there are no other elements than shown in your comment then I agree with Eric that you can simply edit the templates suggested to output both `Detail` and `Low` respectively `Header` and `High`.